# Probability Problem, chips in a bowl

Tags: probability

There are five red chips and three blue chips in a bowl. The red chips are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, respectively, and the blue chips are numbered 1, 2, 3, respectively. If two chips are to be drawn at random and without replacement, find the probability that these chips have either the same number or the same color.

Here is what I am thinking but I don't know if it is correct.

Same number: If you pick one out of six chips (the chips that have other chips with their numbers), then for the second chip, there is 1 out of 5 chips that have the same number. Or you can pick one out of the two that don't have chips with the same number as others. So I think it is: 
${6 \choose 2}+{2 \choose 2}$
or maybe it is multiplied and not added together.

Same Color:
${5 \choose 2}+ {3 \choose 2}$

The total number of outcomes is:
${8 \choose 2}$
So that is the denominator in the probability fraction.

So I am thinking:

$\left(\frac{(same \ color) \ + \ (same \ number)}{8 \choose 2}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{{6 \choose 2} \ + \ {2 \choose 2} \ + \ {5 \choose 2} \ + \ {3 \choose 2}}{8 \choose 2}\right) $

That was my thought process, that like I said can be totally wrong. 
Can someone please walk me through the problem?

Comment: One thing that simplifies your problem is that if you pick same color for both, you can't get same numbers and similarly if you pick same numbers for both, you can't get same colors. So your numerator is right. Denominator is the total ways of picking 2, which is also right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denominator is indeed $8 \choose 2$

For the numerator:

Same number: There are just 3 options! Both 1's, both 2's, or both 3's. When you multiply $6\choose 1$ and $5 \choose 1$ you are effectively saying that you can pick 1 of the 6 that have a 'mate', and then you can pick *any* of the 5 others ... that is of course not how it works. There is only 1 option left at that point ... and since order does not matter, you need to further divide by 2, which is how you would get at 3.  But common sense tells you that there are just 3 possibilities here like I said: both 1's, both 2's, or both 3's.

Same color: Both red: ${5 \choose 2}= 10$ options (instead of 20 .. order does not matter!) Both blue ${3 \choose 2}= 3$ options (again, order does not matter)

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question, with your explanation, however I still cannot seem to understand how to put it all together at the end. Do I add or multiply the options within same color?

Comment: @user485656 You just add them: There are 10 possible ways to get two red chips, and there are 3 possible ways to get two blue chips, so this is 13 out of all $8 \choose 2$ possibilities to get two chips of the same color. To that you add the 3 possibilities of getting the same number chips, so total of 16 out of 28 possibilities.  You would only do something like multiplying these options when you would get, say, two red chips *and* two blue chips.  But you're just getting two chips, period.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ denote the event that the chips have the same number and let $C$ denote the event that the chips have the same color.

Then $N\cap C=\varnothing$ so that:

$$P(N\cup C)=P(N)+P(C)=\frac{3}{\binom82}+\frac{\binom52+\binom32}{\binom82}$$

Answer (score 1):

Same number:

you have numbers: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5 - you pick 1 from 8, then 1 from 7 - giving 56 total combinations. of these, there are only 3 successes (duplicate 1,2,3) and two ways of getting each of these, leaving 6/56 chance of success or 3/28

Same colour:

there are again, 56 combinations, if the first one is blue, there are two chances for success, but this can happen 3 times, so there is a 3/28 chance of success with blue. For red, if the first one is red there are 4 chances for success, but 5 ways this can happen, leaving a 20/56 chance for success, or 5/14.

Fortunately there is no scenario where a success is a success for two reasons, as each coloured set has no duplicate numbers. This sums to the total chance of success as 32/56 or 4/7

[Visualisation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bkZI7wMzssmdsb2DVxxx0CScAoTUzmkar_BJ5ZnwTuo/edit?usp=sharing)